# serialization with Jquery

Tags: serialization, jquery-selectors

My problem is as follows. I can't serialize elements contained by

```
<div id="idtab-page-0">
....
</div>
```

My HTLM code can be uploaded here **[HTML code](http://o2website.hol.es/stackoverflow/)** => 3 files

- formulaire.html.txt code complete
- selector.html.txt code without style for a better reading
- DOM.png to display the DOM structure into a browser

I tried

```
var oSerialData = $( '#idTab' ).serialize(); => ""
oSerialData = $( '#idFormulaire #idtab-page-0' ).serialize(); => ""

var test = $( '#idFormulaire' ).find( '#idtab-page-0' ).serialize(); => ""
var serial1 =$( "#idFormulaire :input" ).serialize(); => "cboxClosed=2&pickerDateFin=&Comment=&pickerDateDeb="
serial1 =$( "div" ).serialize(); => ""
serial1 =$( "idFormulaire :checked" ).serialize(); => ""
serial1 =$( "form" ).serialize(); => "cboxClosed=2&pickerDateFin=&Comment=&pickerDateDeb="
```

and the result for `serial1 =$( "#idTab" ).children()` is 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC3so.png)

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I decided to build my own serialize function which is as follows:

```
(function($) 
{   $.fn.serializeFormulaire = function(toReturn) 
    {   //var toReturn  = {};
        var els = $(this).find(':input').get();

        $.each (els, function( i, val ) 
        {   if (this.type !=="button" )
                {   toReturn[this.name] =  this.value; 
                    if (this.type === "radio") 
                    {   if (!$("input[name='" + [this.name] + "']:checked").val())  {   toReturn[this.name] ="NULL"; } 
                        else {  toReturn[this.name] = $("input[name='" + [this.name] + "']:checked").val();}
                    }
                    else if (this.type === "checkbox" && $(this).prop("checked") === false)
                    {   //alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
                        toReturn[this.name] = "";
                    }
                }
        });
        //return toReturn;  
    };
})(jQuery);
```

To serialize a form, code this:

```
$("#FormName").serializeFormulaire(oSerialData);
```

I don't need to return toReturn variable in serializeFormulaire because I pass in the anonymous function toReturn which is in my example oSerialData variable.